# Does <c:when> act like `else if` or `if`?

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

Using the jstl core taglib, I have multiple conditions I want to check using `<c:choose>`.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${obj1.enabled}">
        ${obj1.name}
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${obj2.enabled}">
        ${obj2.name}
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <spring:message code="error.NoRecordFound"/>
    </c:otherwise>
<c:choose>
```

I read this as "if object 1 is enabled, print its name, else if object 2 is enabled, print its name, else print error message".

But both `obj1` and `obj2` could both be enabled, and I'm concerned that it's actually going to behave as "If object 1 is enabled, print its name. If object 2 is enabled, print its name. If none of the previous conditions were true, print error message."

All of the examples of using multiple `<c:when>`'s I have found online provide conditions which are mutually-exclusive, such as `n < 100` and `n > 1000`, or a dummy string in place of conditions, e.g. `<c:when test="condition 1 here">` and `<c:when test="condition 2 here">`. So it's not clear from the examples I've found whether it's if/else-if/else or it's if/if/if-none-of-the-above.

Comment: How about just trying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`<c:choose>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/choose.html) (emphasis mine):

> Simple conditional tag that establishes a context for **mutually exclusive** conditional operations, marked by `<when>` and `<otherwise>`